# WPF: Dictionary<int, List<string>> in DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a `Dictionary<int, List<string>>`. Each ID(int) has a corresponding dynamic list of names(`List<string>`).

This is the expected output in Datagrid.

```
ID | Name | Name | Name
1    Ash    Tina   Kara
2    Kc     
3    Star   Lara
```

How do I achieve this?

Comment: Are you sure you need `DataGrid` for that? Why not use `ListView` with custom template or something.

Comment: Listview will be fine as long as its editable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
 <DataGrid x:Name="dg" ItemsSource="{Binding Dic}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="id" Binding="{Binding Key}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Value[0]}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Value[1]}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Value[2]}"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
```

[image]

if Name is not a fixed data, you need add column dynamicly like this:

```
 DataGridTextColumn column = new DataGridTextColumn();
            column.Header = "name4";
            column.Binding = new Binding("Value[3]");
            dg.Columns.Add(column);
```

all right ,here is my code:

```
 <DataGrid x:Name="dg" ItemsSource="{Binding Dic}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="id" Binding="{Binding Key}"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>


private Dictionary<int, List<string>> dic;

        public Dictionary<int, List<string>> Dic
        {
            get { return dic; }
            set { dic = value; }
        }

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.DataContext = this;
            Dic = new Dictionary<int, List<string>>();
            Dic.Add(1, new List<string> { "a", "b", "c", "5" });
            Dic.Add(2, new List<string> { "d" });
            Dic.Add(3, new List<string> { "e", "f" });

            int count = 0;
            foreach (List<string> lst in Dic.Values)
            {
                if (lst.Count > count)
                {

                    for (int i = count; i < lst.Count; i++)
                    {
                        DataGridTextColumn column = new DataGridTextColumn();
                        column.Header = "name" + i;
                        column.Binding = new Binding(string.Format("Value[{0}]", i));
                        dg.Columns.Add(column);
                    }
                    count = lst.Count;
                }
            }


        }
```

but i'd like you finish it by yourself

Comment: Thanks but the number of columns for the names should be dynamic. It could be more than 3.

Comment: Simple and easy solution, but the grid's not editable.

Comment: Can you also post Code behind for this @Rang for displaying data in rows ? Thanks.

Comment: Thanks @rang! I'll finish it. So sorry, Im a newbie in WPF.

Comment: How to apply template on cells, using this approach?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to bind to the `Values` collection of the dictionary? Set the `dictionary.Values` collection as the `ItemsSource` and turn on `AutoGenerateColumns=True`