# WPF MVVM, how to can we display a dictionary<string,List<string>> horizontally with editing enabled

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I'm pretty new to WPF MVVM. I'm looking for a solution where I can display my dictionary in a view horizontally. 
Basically i want something like this[Please click here for image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ytLVg.png)

If anyone could help please.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Possible duplicate of this [WPF: Dictionary> in DataGrid](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24361223/5134119)

You need to bind inner list items dynamically. Refer above thread with similar problem.

Good luck! (Do not forget to mark this as answer if you find it helpful)

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer. Please be patient until you have enough reputation to comment.

Comment: @Clemens: Then what should be done if I want to assist in Q&A thread! That answer is well directed to solution. If you know, I don't have enough reputation to comment why "down vote", , bother to elaborate?

Comment: Be patient until you have enough reputation. I've downvoted your answer because it doesn't explain anything. Besides a vague, pointless hint it just contains a link to another Q&A. I've also voted to delete it. You may however just delete it yourself.